# Advice on how I can decrease Kafka Lag

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I'm relatively new to working with Kafka, below is a sample of what my current set up is.

[Kafka Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxpkB.jpg)

Multiple topics that all have one partition each. 2 Consumer Groups with each group containing one consumer.

The issue I am seeing is that the Lag is enormous, sometimes upwards of 8-10 hours waiting for consuming, the load is about 100-200 million messages a day

What steps should I look at in order to address this? Is it as simple as reassigning partitions or creating new partitions for the 3 topics that are being consumed by the two consumers? - I've also looked at compressing the contents of the producer with gzip but it doesn't really help in terms of the lag. I've looked at network connections and don't feel that it is anything got to do with this. If anyone could point me in the direction of Kafka and Low Latency documents that would be good also.

Comment: Your diagram doesn't really make sense. Partition 0 only applies to one topic, not multiple of them. Beyond that, no, you cannot scale your consumer threads or instances beyond the number of partitions

Answer (score 3):

Generally the flow is to parallelize your consumption through the increase on the number of partitions and consumers in consumer groups that subscribe to those topics with increased partitions (Nconsumers <= Npartitions).
And distribute your topics with increase on the number of brokers in your cluster.

So from topic considerations:

Less partition per topic result:

- in producer and/or consumer lag
- starved or overloaded brokers and consumers.

(But take into account) More partition per topic result in:

- More broker resources – file handlers and memory.
- There is an overhead with each additional partition and a number of partitions a broker can handle is limited.
- Overhead of replication load

Then increase the number of consumers in that consumer groups.

> Try increasing partition per topic, but by itself it should not help! You also will need to increase the number of consumers in your consumer group. Is that single consumers or consumer groups on your [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxpkB.jpg)? How many consumers in your consumer group vs partitions on the topic that they are subscibed to.

From this in your message:

> I've also looked at compressing the contents of the producer with gzip but it doesn't really help in terms of the lag.

I get an idead that your messages may be huge! Is it so? In case yes, try to keep messages small (for example by excluding BLOBs and keep external links to them)

Still the issue may be somewhere else like bad configs, consumer commit messages (acknowledgment handling), etc.

So, I highly advice you to read article [Fine-tune Kafka performance with the Kafka optimization theorem](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/05/03/fine-tune-kafka-performance-kafka-optimization-theorem#optimization_goals_for_kafka)
[image]

I also advise you to go through Apache Kafka courses on [Confluent web-page](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/apache-kafka/topics/)

This should be added as a comment, but I haven't had permissions to do so. The provided info is very limited with incorrect [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxpkB.jpg), which limits the ability to provide an adequate helpfull answer. If possible please correct your [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxpkB.jpg) and add more details about your set-up like:

- broker configuration, file attached;
- consumer set-up (Consumer commit messages);
- producer set-up;
- topic set-up;
- kafka version (the defaults differ with major/minor versions)
  The provided [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxpkB.jpg) is not correct in the notion of topic - partition relationship, so I assume it is a mistype and Partition 0 must be substituded with Broker 0, right?

> Kafka's topics are divided into several partitions. While the topic is a logical concept in Kafka, a partition is the smallest storage unit that holds a subset of records owned by a topic...

Then there is an open question on the number of partiotions in each topic and the number of topics in each broker, as well as the number of brokers in your cluster!